# Is it permissable for disabled people to procreate?

Tags: fiqh, children, disability, morality

Let's say one in a married couple or both of them have some sort of mental or physical disability (a serious one perhaps), and reproducing has a high chance of making the offspring suffer from the same disability which might or will lead to the child from suffering extremely throughout its life. Let's say the couple has no empathy and decency at all and decides to reproduce anyways. Is it morally acceptable in Islam to procreate in this case or are there no rules regarding this matter?

Comment: Have you come across any daleel that would prohibit procreation for the physically disabled?

Comment: @Ahmed had I come across any daleel on the matter at all, I wouldn't have needed to ask this question here at all now would I?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've not come across any evidence to prohibit them (physically handicapped) from having kids. I know 2 separate couples with physical disabilities (polio) but alhmd their children are normal and healthy. Your question might be more of a moral one than a religious one. Allah knows best.